# How to use dateformat() in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

When I try to format a date using the `DateFormat` function, like this:

```
with table1 as (select date(2018,3,08) as d1)
select DateFormat(date(d1), 'yyyy-MM-dd')as d2 from table1;
```

the following error is returned:

```
Error: Function not found: DateFormat at [2:8]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First - `DATE(2018,3,08)` is already of DATE datatype and returns date as `2018-03-08` so you do not need to do any extra formatting

Second - if still for whatever reason need to format it into string as let's say `MM-DD-YYYY` you can use [`FORMAT_DATE`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#format_date) function as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH table1 AS (
  SELECT DATE(2018,3,08) AS d1
)
SELECT d1, FORMAT_DATE('%m-%d-%Y', d1) AS d2
FROM table1
```

with output as

```
Row d1          d2   
1   2018-03-08  03-08-2018
```